# go: How to define dependencies?

Tags: go, dependencies

How are dependencies specified in go?

For example in node.js you have `package.json` and you define dependencies like this: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Is there a "meta" definition like `package.json` in go?

Comment: The Go language doesn't define dependencies anywhere except in the source itself.

Answer (score 3):

No, each source file import packages, you specify the main file (your entry point) when you compile. The dependency graph is built on the fly at compile time. Circular dependencies are forbidden.